# Turning python function with user input into web app?

Tags: javascript, python, html, web, widget

okay so I've been coding for a little bit and I'm trying to understand how everything comes together. I'm pretty efficient in python and learning java. and took web development course so understand HTML,widgets,a little JS. My question... Would it be possible to create a hang man game in python and then have that posted on a web page? or something like that would never be done? what are web widgets made with then?

like this one:
    import random#imports random

```
#Author
#File name: Lab01.py
#Date: 1/30/2014

#Purpose: allow user to play the game of hangman
#inputs:none
#outputs: Text that resembles the game of hangman
def main():
    wordList=["max","cat","basket","ship","earth","coat","ocean","beach"]#creates set of words for game to chose from

    userAnswer=raw_input("Type 1 or any button to play, 2 to quit: ")
    while userAnswer != "2":
        theWord=wordList[random.randint(0,len(wordList)-1)]
        theWordList=[]
        brickDisplay=[]
        letterList=[]
        count=0#sets count to 0
        statementCount=0#sets statement count to 0

        for i in range (len(theWord)):
            theWordList.append(theWord[i])#creates list of each character of the word   
        brickDisplay=[]
        for i in range (len(theWordList)):
            brickDisplay.append("-")#Creates the same number of underscores that there are letters in the word
        print brickDisplayMaker(brickDisplay)
        letterChoice=raw_input("Enter a letter: ")
        conditionEnd=conditionChecker(statementCount)#updates conditionEnd
        wordEnd=wordChecker(theWordList,brickDisplay)#updates wordEnd
        while wordEnd != "stop" and conditionEnd != "stop":
                while letterChoice in letterList: #Checks if letter has already been entered by user
                    print "You've already entered that"
                    letterChoice=raw_input("Enter a letter: ")

                else:
                    letterList.append(letterChoice)
                    for i in range(len(theWordList)):
                        if theWordList[i]==letterChoice:
                            count=count+1#counts the number of times letterChoice was in the word
                            brickDisplay[i]=theWordList[i]
                    print brickDisplayMaker(brickDisplay)
                    if count==0:
                        statementCount=statementCount+1
                        statementProducer(statementCount,theWord)
                    conditionEnd=conditionChecker(statementCount)
                    wordEnd=wordChecker(theWordList,brickDisplay)
                    count=0
                    if wordEnd=="stop":
                        print "You've Won!"
                    elif conditionEnd=="stop":
                        print "You have lost, the word was "+theWord #lets user know what the word was
                    else:    
                        letterChoice=raw_input("Enter a letter: ")


        userAnswer=raw_input("Type 1 or any button to play, 2 to quit: ")
    print "Thanks for playing" #exists main
#Purpose: Check if words are the same
#Inputs: theWordList, brickDisplay
#outputs: "stop" or "go"
def wordChecker(theWordList,brickDisplay):
    count=0
    for i in range(len(theWordList)):
        if theWordList[i]!=brickDisplay[i]:
            count=count+1
    if count==0:
        return "stop"
    else:
        return "go"
#Purpose: Check if statement count equals 6
#inputs: StatementCount
#outputs: "stop" or "go"
def conditionChecker(statementCount):
    if statementCount==6:
        return "stop"
    else:
        return "go"

#Purpose: Create the brickDisplay with spaces between the underscores
#Inputs: brickDisplay
#Outputs:bricksDisplay with spaces between the underscores
def brickDisplayMaker(brickDisplay):
    officialBrickDisplay=""
    for ndx in brickDisplay:
        officialBrickDisplay=officialBrickDisplay+ndx+" "#creates new list with spaces between underscores
    return officialBrickDisplay 
#Purpose: Produces statement based on the statementCount
#Inputs: statementCount
#Outputs: Statement
def statementProducer(statementCount,theWord):
    if statementCount ==1:
        print "Draw body part: head"
    elif statementCount==2:
        print "Draw body part: body"
    elif statementCount==3:
        print "Draw body part: left arm"
    elif statementCount==4:
        print "Draw body part: right arm"
    elif statementCount==5:
        print "Draw body part: left leg"
    else:
        print "Draw body part: right leg"



main()
```

Comment: You can make websites in python, yes.

Comment: Yep .. you could try [skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org) which is python implemented in javascript. So any pure python code should run in browser as well without changing anything.

Comment: so I was looking at that website I can enter my python in a website. but say im creating a website and i just want the output of my python to show in website and not the code(that I would have in my website code)

Answer (score -1):

This depends on the technology you would like to use. If you want to stick to Python, you could work into Django, for example: https://www.djangoproject.com/

For JavaScript, there are dozens of frameworks; [This is a famous website](http://todomvc.com/) where different frameworks were used to perform the same task, a simple todo app.

Eventually, it's up to your preference. Personally, I like [Meteor](https://www.meteor.com/) very much, but it might be an overkill for you, as it's designed for realtime web applications. It all depends on what you are targeting.

Comment: thanks for the answer okay. So i download django? and then i would give it a py file or enter my code and it would give me something i could put in html. or am i not understanding how it works?

Comment: Actually, it is not *that* easy. Do you mind explaining what you would like to do? I don't know skulpt, though. So I am not sure whether that can do what you need.

Comment: just a random example lets say I wanted to post this on a html:

Comment: im gonna post it in the quesiton